# Chrome redirecting even when the server is down

Tags: google-chrome, dns, redirection

On an internal server recently we had a redirect to an external site set up. Whilst we were upgrading Apache and switching around the server configuration, this redirect was removed from Apache's httpd.conf or httpd-ssl.conf (it was in one or the other, cannot remember which).

However, a strange issue persisted on a single machine: whenever you type in **http://www**.site.com, the client is redirected to this external site. Even if the server is down. This appears to be an issue with Google Chrome, as there is no redirection in Firefox, IE, or Opera. This issue does not occur with **http://**site.com, nor **https://www.**site.com.

I've tried flushing the Windows DNS cache (`ipconfig /flushdns`), and I've tried flushing Chrome's DNS cache (`chrome://net-internals#dns`), but the issue persists.

Preferably, I would like there to be a way to resolve this issue without reinstalling Chrome on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is being stored in your cache. Clear your browsing history, specifically your cache.

Open the Chrome History and click the Clear all browsing data... button. Select "Empty the cache" from "the beginning of time", and the phantom redirect should go away.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even think to empty the standard cache.

Comment: I updated the redirect location for one of my sub-domains, which took effect in Firefox, but Chrome stubbornly kept going to the old location. This fixed it. +1.